selenide https request seems to be http
I think the problem I am getting performing a basic selenide test getting the following error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name 
[0x160x030x010x0220x010x000x02.0x030x03!0x050xf80xd80xd30xd0*0xfa0x95N0xfa0x7fg0xf3o0x8c0xda0x090xbb0xbf0xcc0xc00xcca0x7f0xf30x910x18]A0x950x0b ].
HTTP method names must be tokens

is due to the open calling HTTP not https.
The test code.
@Test
public void adminCanLoginByUsername() {
    open("https://localhost.local:8443/login");
    $(By.name("username")).setValue("Admin");
    $(By.name("password")).setValue("p455word");
    $("#submit").click();
    assertEquals("https://localhost.local:" + port + "/index", webdriver().object().getCurrentUrl());
    assertTrue($("#admin-menu-item").isEnabled());
}

I see the browser window flash up. In debug setting a breakpoint on the following instruction its never hit.
Full log
    05-04-2024 13:11:05,890 +0100 INFO i.g.b.w.WebDriverManager [cfg-Test worker] Using chromedriver 123.0.6312.86 (resolved driver for Chrome 123)
05-04-2024 13:11:05,900 +0100 INFO i.g.b.w.WebDriverManager [cfg-Test worker] Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as /home/ian/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/123.0.6312.86/chromedriver
05-04-2024 13:11:06,103 +0100 INFO c.e.LoginTest [cfg-Test worker] Starting LoginTest using Java 21.0.2 with PID 16383 (started by ian in /home/ian/IdeaProjects/DemoCode)
05-04-2024 13:11:06,104 +0100 DEBUG c.e.LoginTest [cfg-Test worker] Running with Spring Boot v3.2.4, Spring v6.1.5
05-04-2024 13:11:06,104 +0100 INFO c.e.LoginTest [cfg-Test worker] The following 1 profile is active: "jdbc"
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
05-04-2024 13:11:06,764 +0100 INFO c.e.TestConfig [cfg-Test worker] Initialising Test Config.
05-04-2024 13:11:06,823 +0100 INFO o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer [cfg-Test worker] Tomcat initialized with ports 8080 (http), 8443 (https)
05-04-2024 13:11:06,830 +0100 INFO o.a.c.c.StandardService [cfg-Test worker] Starting service [Tomcat]
05-04-2024 13:11:06,830 +0100 INFO o.a.c.c.StandardEngine [cfg-Test worker] Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
05-04-2024 13:11:06,862 +0100 INFO o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/] [cfg-Test worker] Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
05-04-2024 13:11:06,863 +0100 INFO o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext [cfg-Test worker] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 746 ms
05-04-2024 13:11:06,903 +0100 TRACE o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping [cfg-Test worker] 
    c.e.c.PageController:
    { [/index || /]}: index(HttpServletRequest,Model)
    {GET [/login]}: login(Model)
    { [/hello/{who}]}: hello(String,Model)
    { [/suggestions]}: suggestions(HttpServletRequest,Model)
    {POST [/performlogin]}: performLogin(LoginModel,Model)
    {GET [/health]}: health()
    {GET [/login-error]}: loginError(Model)
    {GET [/add/{veg}]}: addVegetable(String,HttpServletRequest,Model)
    { [/clear]}: clearSelected(HttpServletRequest,Model)
    { [/recipe]}: getRecipe(HttpServletRequest,Model)
05-04-2024 13:11:06,907 +0100 TRACE o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping [cfg-Test worker] 
    c.e.c.AdminController:
    {POST [/addnewveg]}: addNewVeg(MultipartFile,String)
    {GET [/removeveg]}: removeveg(Model)
    {GET [/addveg]}: addveg()
    {GET [/admin]}: getAdmin(Model)
    { [/403]}: accessDenied()
    {PUT [/updateuser], produces [text/html]}: updateuser(String)
    {GET [/remove/{veg}]}: addVegetable(String,Model).springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1c98fe6f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@774304ca, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWr
05-04-2024 13:11:06,910 +0100 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping [cfg-Test worker] 17 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
05-04-2024 13:11:06,912 +0100 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping [cfg-Test worker] Detected 0 mappings in 'beanNameHandlerMapping'
05-04-2024 13:11:06,916 +0100 TRACE o.s.w.s.f.s.RouterFunctionMapping [cfg-Test worker] 0 RouterFunction(s) in 'routerFunctionMapping'
05-04-2024 13:11:06,929 +0100 TRACE o.s.s.c.a.a.c.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer [cfg-Test worker] Eagerly initializing {testConfig=coding.example.TestConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0@2d4e99de}
iterFilter@3e595da3,05-04-2024 13:11:06,985 +0100 INFO o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter [cfg-Test worker] Validated configuration attributes org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@1397b141, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7c03f9d0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@559c4e06, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5e763c07, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4cd90c36, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@aa23f11, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@579dde54, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4bdef487, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@12bcf7c6]
05-04-2024 13:11:06,986 +0100 INFO o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain [cfg-Test worker] Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@b2d8dcd, org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@771d4db, org
05-04-2024 13:11:06,997 +0100 DEBUG o.s.s.c.a.w.c.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy [cfg-Test worker] Filter 'springSecurityFilterChain' configured for use
05-04-2024 13:11:07,153 +0100 INFO o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo [cfg-Test worker] No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
05-04-2024 13:11:07,412 +0100 INFO o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean [cfg-Test worker] Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
05-04-2024 13:11:07,466 +0100 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter [cfg-Test worker] ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
05-04-2024 13:11:07,481 +0100 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver [cfg-Test worker] ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
   .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.4)
WARNING: A Java agent has been loaded dynamically (/home/ian/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.14.12/be4984cb6fd1ef1d11f218a648889dfda44b8a15/byte-buddy-agent-1.14.12.jar)
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is in use, please run with -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to hide this warning
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is not in use, please run with -Djdk.instrument.traceUsage for more information
WARNING: Dynamic loading of agents will be disallowed by default in a future release
unknown error: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.86)9}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:34109/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 123.0.6312.86, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {i
Build info: version: '4.19.1', revision: 'abe0ee07dc'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.14.21-150500.55.52-default', java.version: '21.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [f5dfda5e6c8c2aaa16212c720b60e5fc, get {url=https://localhost.local:8443/login}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 123.0.6312.86, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 123.0.6312.86 (9b72c47a0536..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:34109}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:34109/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 123.0.6312.86, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
selenide.baseUrl: https://localhost.local:8443
Session ID: f5dfda5e6c8c2aaa16212c720b60e5fc
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.86)9}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:34109/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 123.0.6312.86, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {i
Build info: version: '4.19.1', revision: 'abe0ee07dc'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.14.21-150500.55.52-default', java.version: '21.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [f5dfda5e6c8c2aaa16212c720b60e5fc, get {url=https://localhost.local:8443/login}]
selenide.url: https://localhost.local:8443/login
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 123.0.6312.86, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 123.0.6312.86 (9b72c47a0536..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:34109}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:34109/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 123.0.6312.86, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
selenide.baseUrl: https://localhost.local:8443
Session ID: f5dfda5e6c8c2aaa16212c720b60e5fc
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodec.decode(ErrorCodec.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:300)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteNavigation.to(RemoteWebDriver.java:1063)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.Navigator.lambda$navigateTo$0(Navigator.java:72)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.SelenideLogger.lambda$run$0(SelenideLogger.java:105)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.SelenideLogger.wrap(SelenideLogger.java:133)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.SelenideLogger.run(SelenideLogger.java:104)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:68)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.drivercommands.Navigator.open(Navigator.java:31)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.SelenideDriver.open(SelenideDriver.java:93)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:53)
    at coding.example.LoginTest.adminCanLoginByUsername(LoginTest.java:42)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)

05-04-2024 13:11:07,528 +0100 INFO o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer [cfg-Test worker] Tomcat started on ports 8080 (http), 8443 (https) with context path ''
05-04-2024 13:11:07,529 +0100 TRACE o.s.w.s.r.ResourceUrlProvider [cfg-Test worker] No resource handling mappings found
05-04-2024 13:11:07,530 +0100 INFO c.e.LoginTest [cfg-Test worker] Started LoginTest in 1.614 seconds (process running for 2.582)383_1
05-04-2024 13:11:07,630 +0100 INFO c.c.s.i.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer [cfg-Test worker] No webdriver is bound to current thread: 1 - let's create a new webdriverloads/1712319067633_16383_1] in 1 [size=1]
05-04-2024 13:11:07,634 +0100 INFO c.c.s.i.FileHelper [cfg-Test worker] Creating folder: /home/ian/IdeaProjects/DemoCode/build/downloads/1712319067633_16383_1
05-04-2024 13:11:08,578 +0100 INFO c.c.s.w.WebDriverFactory [cfg-Test worker] BrowserName=chrome Version=123.0.6312.86 Platform=linux
05-04-2024 13:11:08,578 +0100 INFO c.c.s.w.WebDriverFactory [cfg-Test worker] Selenide v. 7.2.3
05-04-2024 13:11:08,578 +0100 INFO c.c.s.w.WebDriverFactory [cfg-Test worker] Selenium WebDriver v. 4.19.1 build revision: abe0ee07dc
05-04-2024 13:11:08,578 +0100 INFO c.c.s.d.CreateDriverCommand [cfg-Test worker] Created webdriver in thread 1: ChromeDriver -> ChromeDriver: chrome on linux (f5dfda5e6c8c2aaa16212c720b60e5fc), downloadsFolder: /home/ian/IdeaProjects/DemoCode/build/downloads/1712319067633_16
05-04-2024 13:11:08,579 +0100 INFO c.c.s.d.DisposablesRegistry [cfg-Test worker] Register WebDriverInstance[config=StaticConfig, webDriver=ChromeDriver: chrome on linux (f5dfda5e6c8c2aaa16212c720b60e5fc), proxy=null, downloadsFolder=/home/ian/IdeaProjects/DemoCode/build/down
05-04-2024 13:11:08,582 +0100 INFO c.c.s.d.DisposablesRegistry [cfg-Test worker] Add shutdown hook in 1 [size=1]
05-04-2024 13:11:08,602 +0100 INFO o.a.c.h.Http11Processor [cfg-http-nio-8443-exec-1] Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x02R0x010x000x02N0x030x030x0c0xad0x030x17|0xd20x940x08~0x8e0x8f|0xf60x7f10xa40xcb0x110xca0xeb0xfd0xe70x100xec0x8f%p0x93n00xbc7 ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:407) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) [?:?]
05-04-2024 13:11:08,602 +0100 INFO o.a.c.h.Http11Processor [cfg-http-nio-8443-exec-2] Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x120x010x000x020x0e0x030x030xc40xbc0x12q0x9eL0xb60x1c0xf20x01p0x90%0xa90x100xc00x8d0x07XWu1q0x98y0xb40x11r0xba0xeb0x9f0xae ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:407) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) [?:?]
05-04-2024 13:11:08,706 +0100 INFO c.c.s.d.DisposablesRegistry [cfg-Thread-6] Run cleanup: size=1
05-04-2024 13:11:08,707 +0100 INFO c.c.s.i.FileHelper [cfg-Thread-6] Deleted empty folder: /home/ian/IdeaProjects/DemoCode/build/downloads/1712319067633_16383_1
05-04-2024 13:11:08,707 +0100 INFO c.c.s.d.CloseDriverCommand [cfg-Thread-6] Close webdriver: 103 -> ChromeDriver: chrome on linux (f5dfda5e6c8c2aaa16212c720b60e5fc)...
> Task :test
LoginTest > adminCanLoginByUsername() FAILED
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException at LoginTest.java:42
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:44567', transport: 'socket'
05-04-2024 13:11:08,712 +0100 INFO o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean [cfg-SpringApplicationShutdownHook] Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> Task :test FAILED

Any ideas, I have exhausted Google, no solution found :(
System info: Suse Linux, JDK 21, springboot 3.2.3, Gradle 8.6 using Kotlin DSL, selenide 7.2.3
